# Dropbox API not working on python script run but is working on interactive mode

Tags: python, terminal, dropbox-api

A simple check if the Dropbox API works, I have below dropbox.py script created

```
import dropbox

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('MY_TOKEN')

dbx.users_get_current_account()
```

Running it in normal script mode using terminal, I have to use below command.

```
username$ python3 dropbox.py
```

This returns below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dropbox
```

It works okay when using the interactive mode with below command

```
username$ python3
Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  6 2018, 11:51:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dropbox
>>> dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('MY_TOKEN')
>>> dbx.users_get_current_account()
FullAccount displayed here successfully
```

Why is there a difference in interactive versus script mode? How to get the script mode working?

Comment: That is because you have named you script dropbox.py. change that to dropbox_test.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the issue is name clutch between your file `dropbox.py` and module.

When running `dropbox.Dropbox`, python tries to create instance of `Dropbox` class from your file (which is treated as module too), and you have no such.

The motivation behind this order of imports is ability to "override" pre-installed modules with your own.

TL;DR: renaming your file should help.